# Is $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-u} \Delta u < \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

**Question.** *Let $u : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function such that
$$
u(x, y) > 0 \quad\text{and}\quad \Delta u(x, y) > 0
$$
for all $(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, where $\Delta := \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}$ is the Laplacian. Is the integral
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-u(x,y)} \Delta u(x, y) \; dx\, dy
$$
finite?*

I tried to no avail to find a counterexample where $u$ is rotationally symmetric, i.e. $u(x, y) = f(x^2 + y^2)$ for some $f$. The problem reduces to the following:

**Subquestion.**
*Let $f : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a smooth function such that $f(t) > 0$ and $t f''(t) + f'(t) > 0$ for all $t \in [0, \infty)$.
Is $$
\int_0^\infty e^{-f(t)} (t f''(t) + f'(t)) dt
$$
finite?*

But it is still not clear to me whether or not this initegral will be finite under the given conditions. I tried many different $f$, but the integral always converge.

Comment: Do you need $u$, $\Delta u $ to be strictly positive or just nonegative?

Comment: @user2628206 Strictly positive.

Comment: If $u$ is smooth does not not mean that also $\nabla u$ is smooth. Then, $\Delta u$ can be discontinuous, which may lead to a divergent integral.

Comment: @the_candyman By smooth, I mean infinitely differentiable.

Comment: Note that the second term in your 'counterexample' evaluates to $-(f(\infty)-f(0))$.

Comment: Assume $f(t)=-t^{m}$. It follows $f'(t)=-mt^{m-1}$ and $tf''(t)=-m(m-1)t^{m-1}$, thus the integral is $-m^{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{dt}t^{m-1}e^{t^{m}}$, which is divergent.

Comment: take e.g. m=2...

Comment: @KirylPesotski $f$ is positive.

Comment: @dezdichado sorry then, I shall take "either work carefully or carefully spend time on various forums" as the life philosophy really =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1.** For the original question, consider the function

$$u(x, y) = x^2 + 1.$$

Then we have both $u > 0$ and $\Delta u = 2 > 0$. However,

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-u} \Delta u \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} 2e^{-x^2-1} \, \mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y = +\infty. $$

---

**2.** Given that the answer to the original question is negative, the subquestion becomes more interesting. Although I have no decisive answer, I suspect that the answer is yes. Here is my approach so far:

- Write $\psi(t) = tf'(t)$ and note that the statement is equivalent to the existence of a smooth function $\psi : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\psi(0) = 0$, $\psi'(t) > 0$, and

  $$ I := \int_{0}^{\infty} \exp\left(-\int_{0}^{t} \frac{\psi(s)}{s} \, \mathrm{d}s \right) \, \mathrm{d}\psi(t) < +\infty. $$

  Then $ I \leq \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathrm{d}\psi(t) = \lim_{t\to\infty} \psi(t) $, and so, any counter-example must satisfy $\psi(t) \to +\infty$ as $t \to +\infty$. For this reason, we may add this condition to the assumption on $\psi$.
- Define $\Phi(t) = \int_{0}^{t} s \, \mathrm{d}\log\psi^{-1}(s) $. Then $\Phi$ is also smooth, and it is strictly increasing if and only if $\psi$ is strictly increasing. Also, by substituting $t \mapsto \psi^{-1}(t)$, we get

  $$ \int_{\varepsilon}^{\infty} \frac{\Phi(t)}{t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t = \frac{\Phi(\varepsilon)}{\varepsilon} + \log\left(\frac{\psi^{-1}(\infty)}{\psi^{-1}(\varepsilon)}\right) \qquad \text{and} \qquad \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\Phi(t)} \, \mathrm{d}t = I $$

  for each $\varepsilon > 0$.

Summarizing, the answer to the subquestion will be *yes* if for any smooth, strictly increasing function $\Phi : [0, \infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\Phi(0) = 0$ and $\int_{\varepsilon}^{\infty} \frac{\Phi(t)}{t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t = +\infty$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$, we have

$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\Phi(t)} \, \mathrm{d}t < +\infty. $$